# Canceling points-booked United flight?

Tags: bookings, loyalty-programs, cancellations, united-airlines

Does anyone know if it is possible to cancel points-booked United flight (with refund?)? I booked flights to Portugal for end of November, but now having second thoughts due to all that Ebola stuff. I been thinking to go instead to Chile or Peru.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but it seems that postponing a trip *to Portugal* based on this seems completely out of proportion at this stage.

Comment: You're more likely to die from homicide in [Chile or Peru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_intentional_homicide_rate). I'm sure the odds of homicide there far outweigh the odds of Ebola in Portugal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this chart](http://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/mileageplus/awards/travel/ticketing.aspx), you can cancel the reservation and have the miles re-credited, but there is a fee of up to $200 to do so (if you have elite status it can be less).

If you already know the new flight you want, you can instead change the reservation to the new dates and destination.  Then the fee is only $100 or less.

As far as I know, you would do this through their web site's normal interface for changing or canceling a reservation.  If that doesn't work, call their reservations phone number.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will try to reserve for new dates and destination for lower fee.